# Error when deploying business network to HSBN in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Using Hyperledger Composer v0.7.4 (on Ubuntu 16.04) I have tried deploying a business network to a HSBN in Bluemix, but I get the following error:

```
Error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
```

Had a friend try it on a Mac on my same business network with the same connection profile and it worked. Tried reinstalling everything (even reinstalled Ubuntu) and still no luck.

Here is my connection profile:

```
{
"name": "hlfv1bluemix",
"description": "Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 on Bluemix",
"type": "hlfv1",
"keyValStore": "/home/jeff/.hfc-key-store",
"deployWaitTime": 500,
"invokeWaitTime": 100,
"orderers": [
    {
        "url": "grpcs://ldn1-zbc8a.2.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:10905",
        "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nj6tJLp07kzQoH3jOlOrHvdPJbRzeXDLz\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nCAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
    }
],
"channel": "test",
"mspID": "PeerOrg1",
"ca": "https://ldn1-zbc8a.2.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:10911",
"peers": [
    {
        "requestURL": "grpcs://ldn1-zbc8a.2.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:10921",
        "eventURL": "grpcs://ldn1-zbc8a.2.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:10920",
        "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nj6tJLp07kzQoH3jOlOrHvdPJbRzeXDLz\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nCAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
    },
    {
        "requestURL": "grpcs://ldn1-zbc8c.2.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:10921",
        "eventURL": "grpcs://ldn1-zbc8c.2.secure.blockchain.ibm.com:10920",
        "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nj6tJLp07kzQoH3jOlOrHvdPJbRzeXDLz\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nCAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
    }
]
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Did you try increasing the deploy and invoke timeouts?

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiple timeouts, I even set both to 1000 and still no luck

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu as a VM or the main OS for the machine?

Comment: Main OS, but managed to fix it by setting my DNS to 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by setting my DNS to `8.8.8.8`

Take a look at this question [How do I set my DNS when resolv.conf is being overwritten?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot)